# OpenGL giving triangles colors in a list

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm working in python / PyOpenGL, but the calls are basically mapped straight to OpenGL itself so I'm asking for help from people who know either.

I've got a big 3D system which I've decomposed into facets myself. My first attempt at the code looked something like this:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *

def render(facets):
  for facet in facets:
    glColor( facet['color'] )
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    for v in facet['vertices']:
      glVertex(v)
    glEnd()
```

i.e. I ran over the python objects one at a time, and drew them each individually. The color rendered was set *per facet*, i.e. per triangle, as the triangle's surface color.

Having debugged my code for generating the facets this way, I wanted to render them faster using a native OpenGL list, like this (based on a source snippet from pyglet):

```py
def build_compiled_gllist(vertices, facets):
  """this time, the vertices must be specified globally, and referenced by
  indices in order to use the list paradigm. vertices is a list of 3-vectors, and
  facets are dicts containing 'normal' (a 3-vector) 'vertices' (indices to the 
  other argument) and 'color' (the color the triangle should be)."""

  # first flatten out the arrays:
  vertices = [x for point in vertices for x in point]
  normals = [x for facet in facets for x in facet['normal']]
  indices = [i for facet in facets for i in facet['vertices']]
  colors = [x for facet in facets for x in facet['color']]

  # then convert to OpenGL / ctypes arrays:
  vertices = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)
  normals = (GLfloat * len(normals))(*normals)
  indices = (GLuint * len(indices))(*indices)
  colors = (GLfloat * len(colors))(*colors)

  # finally, build the list:
  list = glGenLists(1)
  glNewList(list, GL_COMPILE)

  glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT)
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices)
  glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals)
  glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors)
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)
  glPopClientAttrib()

  glEndList()

  return list

def run_gl_render(render_list):
  """trivial render function"""
  glCallList(render_list)
```

However, my colors come out completely wrong. The facets are grouped into objects, and within an object all the facet colors should be the same; instead they seem to be completely random.

Looking at other examples, it seems that this array of colors is *per-vertex* rather than *per-facet*. How does that make sense? Vertices are points which by definition can't be rendered - the facets are what are rendered and what have colors! Every vertex in my system is shared between two of the facet-collections / objects, and thus should have two colours to its name.

Someone please clarify how this data is supposed to be structured; I have clearly misunderstood the model I'm working with.

Comment: Could you also post your shader code?

Comment: what is 'shader code'? I'm an openGL novice, my code is mostly copy/paste examples. Do you mean the initialization functions, where I specify lighting etc?

Comment: @tehwalrus, you should really go through some OpenGL tutorials. You won't learn how it works by just trying to adapt existing code examples.

Comment: @GeoffReedy, by all means post an answer pointing me to a relevant tutorial.. :)

Comment: @GeoffReedy (missed the edit window) *edit for clarity:* I have tried looking at every tutorial and example script I can find, seriously if you know where all the good ones are, do share! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, color is specified per-vertex. Depending on the shade model, only one of the colors may be used, but each vertex still gets a color. Your code should work if you replace

```
colors = [x for facet in facets for x in facet['color']]
```

with

```
colors = [x for facet in facets for x in facet['color']*3]
```

to duplicate the color for each vertex. If your normal data is per-face then you will have to do the same for the normal data. Note also that the color and normal values have to match up with the vertices argument, not the indices.

By the way, you can still create a display list using your original code. That is, it's perfectly valid to do

```
def compile_object(facets):
  displist = glGenLists(1)
  glNewList(displist, GL_COMPILE)
  # You can call glColor inside of glBegin/glEnd, so I moved them
  # outside the loop, which might improve performance somewhat
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
  for facet in facets:
    glColor( facet['color'] )
    for v in facet['vertices']:
      glVertex(v)
  glEnd()
  glEndList()
  return displist
```

Try these tutorials

- [Display Lists](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html)
- [Vertex Arrays](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html)

Comment: could you explain how it makes sense to give a point a normal? a plane, I can understand... Also, how the triangles will be colored? the vertices are reused extensively, each may be in 5 or 6 facets, so the `*3` won't work.

Comment: on a separate note, the second solution you suggest will probably work, but won't it be much slower? the idea was to cache the vertices and colors in GPU RAM so that they'd render faster.

Comment: @tehwalrus Attributes (colours, normals, etc.) are specified at vertices and interpolated across whatever primitive is being rendered. In this way planar polygons can be shaded to look like smooth surfaces.

Comment: ...what if I actually want to draw triangles in space? (this is literally what I am visualising, it's a scientific system)

Comment: If you want an attribute to be constant for a whole triangle, there are several approaches, the most basic of which is to duplicate the value at each vertex in the triangle.

Comment: but as I explained, each vertex is reused a bunch of times; it has several different values. Does that mean I should duplicate the vertex in the array, and waste RAM?

Comment: Thanks, I have a couple of ways to do it now.

Comment: A variation on your final example works fine and is fast enough for now, I'll try a vertex-buffer-object (linked from the tutorial you sent me to) later if I need to optimise for speed further. Thanks again! :)